# Windows phone refresh/update listbox items

Tags: c#, listbox, rss, windows-phone

I have a problem with a RSS feed app. When my app launches, the listbox gets the feeds and show them in my listbox, but when i press my refresh button the listbox never updates, it just show the same items again, but if i close the app, and then relaunch it, it will show the latest feeds. I hope there is someone that can help. Thanks.

MainWindow.xaml:

```
<ListBox Grid.Row="1" Name="feedListBox" ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" SelectionChanged="feedListBox_SelectionChanged">
                <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        ...
                        ...
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            </ListBox>
```

MainWindow.cs:

```
private void appBarRefresh_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    feedListBox.ItemsSource = null;

    GetFeed(IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings["key"].ToString());
}

private void GetFeed(string rss)
{
    WebClient webClient = new WebClient();

    webClient.DownloadStringAsync(new System.Uri(rss));
    webClient.DownloadStringCompleted += new DownloadStringCompletedEventHandler(webClient_DownloadStringCompleted);
}

private void webClient_DownloadStringCompleted(object sender, DownloadStringCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Error != null)
    {
        Deployment.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() =>
        {
            MessageBox.Show(e.Error.Message);
        });
    }
    else
    {
        this.State["feed"] = null;
        this.State.Clear();
        this.State["feed"] = e.Result;

        UpdateFeedList(e.Result);
    }
}

private void UpdateFeedList(string feedXML)
{
    StringReader stringReader = new StringReader(feedXML);
    XmlReader xmlReader = XmlReader.Create(stringReader);
    SyndicationFeed feed = SyndicationFeed.Load(xmlReader);

    Deployment.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() =>
    {
        feedListBox.ItemsSource = feed.Items;
    });
    ;
}
```

UPD from comments:

In my `OnNavigatedTo` method I run this code:

```
if (this.State.ContainsKey("feed")) 
{ 
    if (feedListBox.Items.Count == 0) 
    { 
        UpdateFeedList(State["feed"] as string); 
    } 
}
```

Comment: How do you fill feeds list when you open the app first time?

Comment: In my OnNavigatedTo method i run this code:

    if (this.State.ContainsKey("feed"))
            {
                if (feedListBox.Items.Count == 0)
                {
                    UpdateFeedList(State["feed"] as string);
                }
            }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all update this method:

```
private void GetFeed(string rss)
{
    //register event handler first, then call the async method
    WebClient webClient = new WebClient();
    webClient.DownloadStringCompleted += new DownloadStringCompletedEventHandler(webClient_DownloadStringCompleted);
    webClient.DownloadStringAsync(new System.Uri(rss)); 
}
```

**update:**

Looks like your request was cached by OS. What you can do to is to add some random text to your url.

```
webClient.DownloadStringAsync(new System.Uri(rss + "?disablecache="+Environment.TickCount));
```

Comment: Any success? If not, let's try do debug it.

Comment: I will have to wait a little before i can see if it works. Because its getting latest news from the rss, but there has been no new feeds since i started the app, but i will post as soon as i know if it worked :).

Comment: No it didnt work. The problem is still there. When i launch the app first time it shows all the feeds. But when the RSS i get the feeds from gets updated, and i press my refresh button, it still just shows the same feeds.

Comment: Ok, then put a breakpoint to the webClient_DownloadStringCompleted method and check if it is invoked, and if you get updated xml in e.Result

Comment: Okay i tested it. webClient_DownloadStringCompleted method do gets invoked but the xml in e.Result is not updated, it still uses the old data for some reason.

Comment: Okay i will try and see if it works. But is the request cached on my Windows Phone too then?

Comment: I will test and see if it works. I will post back when im sure :).

Comment: By the way, what happens if the Enviroment.TickCount hits the same count again?, would the app crash then?

Comment: Nothing will happen. It is safe, you will never get the same TickCount

Comment: I have one question more. Im trying to get the feeds from this link: http://www.tomshardware.com/feeds/rss2/all.xml but when i add this to refresh it "?disablecache="+Environment.TickCount, it wont show any items. Only if i remove "?disablecache="+Environment.TickCount will it show the feeds, but then i have the problem that i cant refresh it. Can you tell why it doesnt work on this rss feed?. Thanks.

Comment: For this feed you can use (rss + "&disablecache="+ Environment.TickCount);