# How do I get data from multiple XML files in Windows Phone

Tags: c#, xml, windows-phone-7

I have an initial XML file stored in my phone which is accessed to select a number of elements.  Each element has a corresponding online XML file which I need to access to get more information.

```
string name, photo;

foreach (int num in combi)
{
    no = xElem.Descendants("employee").ElementAt(num).Descendants("no").First().Value;
    WebClient wc = new WebClient();
    wc.DownloadStringCompleted += new DownloadStringCompletedEventHandler
        (Info_DownloadStringCompleted);
    wc.DownloadStringAsync(new Uri
        ("http://example.com/" + name));
    list.Add(new Person(no, name, photo);    
}

void Info_DownloadStringCompleted(object sender, DownloadStringCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Error != null) return;
    XElement xml = XElement.Parse(e.Result);
    name = xml.Element("name").Value;
    photo = xml.Element("photo").Value;
}
```

However, it seems that the list.Add goes first before the XML is downloaded resulting into a list with empty values for name and photo.  I confirmed this by placing MessageBox in both the foreach loop and Info_DownloadStringCompleted.  Is there a better way of doing this?

Answer (score 0):

Problem with your solution is that in your iteration over `combi` you'll try to use fields `name` and `photo` which are only assigned to in your eventhandler `Info_DownloadStringCompleted`.

Since `DownloadStringAsync` is, well... asynchronous, you'll exit `foreach` before `DownloadStringCompleted` event is raised, your eventhandler called and ultimately your fields been assigned to.

You can correct this by moving your list-add-logic to be executed after event has been raised.

```
....
wc.DownloadStringCompleted += (sender, args) =>
    {
        // Code from your Info_DownloadStringCompleted event handler
        if (args.Error != null) 
            return;

        XElement xml = XElement.Parse(args.Result);
        name = xml.Element("name").Value;
        photo = xml.Element("photo").Value;

        // Now your fields are assigned and you can do-what-ever-with-'em
        list.Add(new Person(no, name, photo);
    };
....
```

If you like you can use extension methods to utilize `async/await` keywords and make it simpler and easier to read and understand. See SO answer here https://stackoverflow.com/a/13174270/1061668

Then above becomes (remember to mark method `async`)

```
....
// Note that exception is not handled in this example....
xml = await wc.DownloadStringTask(new Uri("http://example.com/" + name));
name = xml.Element("name").Value;
photo = xml.Element("photo").Value;
list.Add(new Person(no, name, photo);
....
```

Comment: Ok, I think this would work.  However, I am planning to display the items in a ListBox.  Where will I put it such that it completes foreach first before trying to place the list in a ListBox?  My foreach is inside a try-catch statement, and I tried placing gridBox.ItemsSource = apps; outside but it seems the List count is still 0.

Comment: It works but you should debug your own code. Maybe this SO question helps you http://stackoverflow.com/q/22295624/1061668

Answer (score 0):

To add to @MikkoVitala's answer, better for you to use [`ObservableCollection`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms668604%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) for the `list`.

`ObservableCollection` has built-in mechanism to notify UI to refresh whenever item added to or removed from collection. So it doesn't matter when you bind `list` to `ListBox`, the `ListBox` will always display up to date member of `list` :

```
string name, photo;
ObservableCollection<Person> list = new ObservableCollection<Person>();

foreach (int num in combi)
{
    .....
}
MyListBox.ItemsSource = list;
```